# unable to click the dropdown element in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

i tried so many xpath in selenium but all were unable to click the element and always give me a error element not found or element not interactable
how to solve it any help would be appreciated
 Here is xpath of the Element is give Below:

```
(//a[@href='javascript:void(0)' and @class='select2-choice select2-default'])[1]
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: (//a[@href='javascript:void(0)' and @class='select2-choice select2-default'])[1]

Comment: don't use @href='javascript:void(0)'

Comment: it makes my xpath unique along with class name

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='s2id_search_input']/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=70.0.3538.97 (d035916fe243477005bc95fe2a5778b8f20b6ae1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `".//*[@id='s2id_search_input']/a"`

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='s2id_search_input']/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=70.0.3538.97 (d035916fe243477005bc95fe2a5778b8f20b6ae1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Wait for element to be clickable before click on it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#s2id_search_input a.select2-choice'))).click()
```

With scroll:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#s2id_search_input a.select2-choice')))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', element)
element.click()
```

Click using JavaScript:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#s2id_search_input a.select2-choice')))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', element)
```

Comment: well i cant not share the url but it prints out Message on console like this Message:

Comment: it still does not click the element